# MacRuby App Icon

Tags: xcode, macos, macruby

I have just written my first "hello world" MacRuby app using XCode. I would like to add a custom application icon. I thought I did this correctly, but when I build my app (using `Project > Archive > Application`) it builds it with the default Mac Application icon. To import my icon (518 x 518 px PNG), I right-clicked the "App Icon" button and selected the file to copy into my project. I can see the file, but it obviously isn't displaying when I open the app.

What did I do wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used MacRuby, but there are two things you have to do to display the right application icon. First, you must convert the PNG file to an icon file. Use the Icon Composer application to convert the PNG file. Icon Composer comes with Xcode. You can find it in the following location:

/Developer/Applications/Utilities

Second, add the icon file to your project. After adding the icon file to your project, you should be able to set the application icon for the project.